# What is the use of block name in Vulkan GLSL?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

Take this GLSL sample code:

```c
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform BlockName {
    mat4 someMtx;
} instanceName;
```

What is the purpose of "BlockName" in this context?

I know you can use the block name to match inputs/outputs of pipeline stages. But what is the purpose for uniform blocks in Vulkan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose is that GLSL *requires it*.

GLSL was made for OpenGL. It can be *used* with Vulkan, but the actual features of GLSL were made to serve the needs of OpenGL. Since Vulkan is a very different API, that means you're going to sometimes have vestigial functionality.

Like these.

In OpenGL, resources are identified, and can be queried, by name. Two resources are the same resource if they use the same name (they also have to match with other properties or an error results, but a name match is a requirement). As such, block names were made part of the grammar of [GLSL interface blocks](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block). You can't *not* have them on any interface blocks (UBOs being a subset of interface blocks).

Vulkan (and SPIR-V) doesn't care about names. For interface variables, the name remains useful because the GLSL code itself uses that name when it wants to access that variable. But block names were *only* used by the external API; they were never used by GLSL code itself.

So when you use a GLSL construct that uses an interface-only name to feed an API that *doesn't care* about interface names, you get block names: a name that needs to exist because GLSL requires it but doesn't actually do the thing GLSL expects it to.

Comment: I see, thanks! I guess it can be useful if you write shaders that can be compiled for both Vulkan and OpenGL?

Comment: @tuket: The whole point of compiling GLSL is that you're working with *GLSL*, not a language that appears to be GLSL but with a bunch of weird syntactic differences. That's why most Vulkan things are exposed via `layout` tags rather than actual changes to the grammar.

Comment: So, if I'm working with GLSL, even if it's GLSL with those Vulkan-specific `layout`  tags, would that same code compile in OpenGL?

Comment: @tuket: That would make for an interesting question. You should ask it using the "Ask a question" button.

Comment: I couldn't find the "Ask a question" button, so I used the "Ask Question" button instead xD:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75348715/1754322. Found the answer myself and posted it. Thanks for your help on the original question! I think considering OpenGL and Vulkan GLSL are not compatible, they could have removed the need for BlockName. Anyways, it is what it is :)